# What is the absolute ceiling of a 737-200?

Tags: aircraft-performance, boeing-737

We're trying to find the official absolute ceiling for the 737-200 for a school project.  So far have only been able to maximum and service ceilings for this craft. Can anyone point us to the correct information for absolute ceiling?  Thanks!

Comment: That will depend on weight, including fuel load

Comment: While it depends on weight, there is a maximum anyway when the aircraft is at its minimum possible weight.

Comment: I don't believe §25 certified transport category aircraft will typically have a published absolute ceiling. Try looking for a Maximum Certified Operating Altitude. In actual practice, maximum altitude attainable will depend on various factors such as air temperature, aircraft loading, and engine limits.

Comment: @JWalters: Why wouldn't they?

Comment: @sean That may be best addressed with a new Q&A. Short answer is that the absolute ceiling is typically well above the certified operating altitude and is therefore not pertinent. Look at various TCDS for examples of the limiting altitudes. One primary limiting factor is time for descent to safe altitude in the case of a pressurization emergency.

Answer (score -2):

Find the pertinent  performance charts for Vx (Max climb angle)and Vy (Max climb rate). You may have to extrapolate, but the altitude where Vx and Vy converge is the Absolute ceiling.

Comment: If the OP cannot find the maximum ceiling value, it's unlikely they can find Vx / Vy charts.

Comment: This is a jet powered, §25 certified aircraft. There will not be a published Vy or Vx.